# Broadcasting a vector into another vector of different size in numpy or python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numba, array-broadcasting

I have `Np` links (pipes) and `Nj` junctions (nodes). Each link `k` has a start node `i` and end node `j`, and a link value of `b`. I want to calculate the contribution of links to each node by adding `b` if the given node is the start node of a link, and substracting `b` if the given node is the end of a link. My code is something like this:

```
for k in range(Np):   #iterate over pipes
    F[i[k]]=F[i[k]]+b[k]   #add value of b if pipe k is at the start of the node
    F[j[k]]=F[j[k]]-b[k]   #substract b if pipe k is at the end of the node
```

An example of the data used to run this code:

```
Np=7   #number of pipes
Nj=6  #number of junctions (nodes)
pipe=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]  #number of pipes are consecutive, k=0:Np
i=[0,1,2,3,3,3,0]     #number of start node for each pipe, 0<=i<Nj
j=[1,5,1,1,2,4,5]     #number of end node for each pipe, 0<=j<Nj
b=[1.3,0.5,1.5,2.7,1.5,2.2,3.1]   #value for each pipe, Np elements
node=[0,1,2,3,4,5]   #node numbers are consecutive, 0:Nj
F=np.zeros(Nj)   #intializing F, size is equal to number of nodes
```

and the result of the loop would be:

```
F=[+1.3+3.1,+0.5-1.3-1.5-2.7,+1.5-1.5,+2.7+1.5+2.2,-2.2,-0.5-3.1]
```

or

```
F=[4.4, -5.0, 0.0, 6.4, -2.2, -3.6]
```

In my own pipe network I have Nj=150628 and Np=157040, so the loop I created takes way too much time (about 0.6s). So I wanted to ask how can I vectorize it? Thanks!
I tried doing the following vectorized code:

```
F=np.zeros(Nj)
F[i]=F[i]+b
F[j]=F[j]-b
F=[ 3.1, -2.2,  0. ,  2.2, -2.2, -3.1,  0. ]
```

Which gives the wrong result because there might be multiple pipes that are at either start or end node of a given node, but it counts only one of them on either side.
Also, would it be faster if I create two sparse matrices Mat_i and Mat_j that represent all pipes connected to start node / end node, and then iterate over that instead? (I'm using python 3.7).

I just managed to get it working with this:

```
F=np.bincount(i,weights=b,minlength=Nj)-np.bincount(j,weights=b,minlength=Nj)
```

I am also open to using Numba as I used `@njit(parallel=True)` in another part of my code for a scalar function & it sped things up alot by using all of the 8 threads of my CPU.

Comment: Isn't `F[j]=F[j]+b` supposed to be `-b` instead of `+b`?

Comment: @JohnZwinck yes thanks I just corrected it

Comment: Are you willing/able to use Numba?  It's a separate library that compiles NumPy code, and it would certainly make quick work of this problem.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I have actually used Numba jit for some of the scalar functions in my code which speed up things significantly, but I didn't know how to apply it here. It would be awesome if you could tell me how to use it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing it with pure NumPy is tricky because you "select" the same index multiple times (i.e. the values in `i` and `j` are not unique).  But Numba will accelerate the code with essentially no changes (I took the liberty of using `+=` for concision):

```
@numba.njit
def smoke(F, b, i, j):
    for k in range(len(i)):   #iterate over pipes
        F[i[k]] += b[k]   #add value of b if pipe k is at the start of the node
        F[j[k]] -= b[k]   #subtract b if pipe k is at the end of the node
```

Run it like this if your inputs are lists:

```
smoke(F, np.asarray(b), np.asarray(i), np.asarray(j))
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, that's very helpful. One problem I have with Numba functions is that they encounter into an error whenever I have to add an if statement inside them. I know using 'if" is not really a parallel thing and I have to use stuff like np.where to avoid it, but it's tricky because the code gets a little complicated.

Comment: @dani: Numba supports `if` just fine.  Maybe there's something else about your code it doesn't like.  Post a new question about it if you want help with that.  Numba is cool!